# Blazor isolated CSS - how do you style a child component based on a parent's class (or pseudo class)?

Tags: css, blazor

Using Blazor isolated CSS, how do you style a child component based on a parent's class (or pseudo class)?

Given this HTML:

```
<ParentComponent>
  <ChildComponent />
</ParentComponent>
```

And this CSS:

```
ParentComponent { display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
ChildComponent { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: yellow; }
```

Of course it's trivial to style the **child** component when you hover over the **parent** component using *normal* CSS like this:

```
ParentComponent:hover ChildComponent { background: blue; }
```

But I'm trying to achieve something similar using Blazor and **isolated CSS**.

The problem is that obviously in this scenario the child component has no awareness of its parent, so how do I get around this? I guess I'm looking for the opposite to the `::deep` pseudo class.

Comment: [Polite] Are you saying you want to conditionally style the Child Component based on different Parent components?  `Parent1 .. child.. background:blue;`, `Parent2... child.. background:red;`  If so then why not stick to normal CSS, if not then why do you need to refer to the parent at all?

Comment: @ShaunCurtis yes I want to conditionally style children based on a class or pseudo class from its parent. Of course I could use normal CSS, but then I lose the benefits of using isolated CSS (i.e. preventing name clashes). I suspect I'll either have to use the `::deep` selector on the parent component's CSS (which goes against the component-based paradigm I'd like to stick to), or pass parameters instead (which is fine in some scenarios, but in situations like `:hover` means tracking mouse events). I guess I was just hoping that there might be a more elegant solution that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I think it's normal CSS or passing parameters, but not being a CSS expert, who knows.  Wait and see who else comments.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isolation does not support upwards breaking-out-of-isolation.

Component abstraction is downward. A component encapsulates it's concerns. Specialization concerning their outsides would mean breaking the generalization and encapsulation aspects of components.

You can either use a `::deep` CSS declaration on the parent or outside components/layouts, or define a CSS rule outside of the components (on the site level).

In the `ParentComponent.razor.css` define

```css
::deep:hover .ChildComponent { background: blue; }
```

This way, the parent component makes use of the general child component, but overwrites its specifics for its own context.